# I just started learning Scripting in Shell Script, RHEL 6.3

Tags: shell, scripting, rhel

How to write in Terminal RHEL 6.3 in a proper way?

If not exist `LOCAL_WORKING_DIR` `LOCAL_EVENT_LOG_WORKING_DIR`
`mkdir LOCAL_WORKING_DIR LOCAL_EVENT_LOG_WORKING_DIR` ????

I have tried with this but seems didnt work
My script :

```
if [! -f ] $LOCAL_WORKING_DIR $LOCAL_EVENT_LOG_WORKING_DIR
    mkdir $LOCAL_WORKING_DIR $LOCAL_EVENT_LOG_WORKING_DIR
```

In Windows we use WINSCP & 7zip right , is it okay to use Nautilus 3.10.1 & p7zip_9.20.1???

Do help me , please :)

Comment: Look at the related questions on the right.  This is a __FAQ__.

Comment: Your question title should be a question rather than story time. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest technique is to use [`mkdir -p`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/mkdir.html) which creates the directory — and any missing directories up the path — and does not fail if the directory already exists, so you can do it all at once with:

```
mkdir -p "$LOCAL_WORKING_DIR" "$LOCAL_EVENT_LOG_WORKING_DIR"
```

Note that the variables are enclosed in double quotes so that even if spaces (etc.) appear in the name, it will work sanely.

Comment: Can u tell the error for me , if [ ! -d "$LOCAL_WORKING_DIR" ] then mkdir "$LOCAL_WORKING_DIR" cd "$LOCAL_WORKING_DIR" else cd"$LOCAL_WORKING_DIR" fi

Comment: Please don't put code in comments; you can't control the formatting.  If you do, you have to be careful to make sure it will work despite the absence of formatting.  What I can see has no semicolons, but semicolons would be necessary if it is all on one line.  Edit your question.  (The `cd "$LOCAL_WORKING_DIR"` should be after the `if` since you change to it regardless. The second one also needs a space between `cd` and `"$LOCAL_WORKING_DIR"`.)

Comment: Syntax error near unexpected token 'else'